# jQuery: getting the id of a <td> within the whole table

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to retrieve the id of a certain table cell within the whole table.

Example

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="current">5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to get the index of `td.current` but not in relation the `<tr>` but of `<table>`

So instead of simply doing

```
$('td.current').index()
```

which will output 1, I need it to output 4 (5th td in the whole table).

Reading the [index() doc](http://api.jquery.com/index/), I've tried multiple stuff but it always returned -1.
I could do this with a loop, but am trying to do it only with selectors.

Is this possible?

Comment: but the code is doing just what it is supposed to.

Comment: The argument to `index()` can be an element like `$('td').index($('.current'))`, although that example is inefficient, so you should probably cache `$('.current')`

Comment: @Ibu you're right. I simplified my example too much. Although j0861 still found the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('.current').index('td');` should do it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/T9pjM/)**

The key part of the index() docs is:

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

So you need to pass in a collection of elements for it to be compared against.

Answer (score 1):

kindly try this ::

```
$('td.current').index('td');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
table = $('.current').parent().children('td');
$('.current').index(table);
```

**EDIT:**

This method is the same as @j08691's, but it only looks inside the table that `.selected` is inside, in case there are more tables on the same page. Otherwise @j08691's answer is better as it uses less code.